# Replace/remove literal square brackets in Bash string

Tags: bash, shell, brackets

I am looking for a solution to eliminate square brackets in a Bash string.
For instance, consider the string:

```
ldr r3, [r0,#8]!
```

However I am not sure how to eliminate the '[' and ']'. I would like to eliminate all symbols in the most elegant way possible, such as:

```
str="ldr r3, [r0,#8]!"
echo ${str//[,.!]/}
```

but with square brackets inclusive. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
echo "${str//[][,.!]}"
```

Because `[]` is not a useful pattern, the `]` is treated as part of the bracket expression when it is the *first* character listed. Bracket expressions cannot be nested, so there is no restriction on the `[`.

You can also simply escape the `]`:

```
echo "${str//[[\],.!]}"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 7):

Another clean solution is tr:

> **tr**: Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard output.

where

> -d, --delete            delete characters in SET1, do not translate

With your example:

```
str="ldr r3, [r0,#8]!"
echo $str | tr -d "[]"
```

the output is:

```
ldr r3, r0,#8!
```

Answer (score 0):

replace literal strings (fixed strings) in bash

[Shell Parameter Expansion - bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> Quoting any part of string inhibits replacement in the expansion of the quoted portion

example

```
a="1[[[2]]]3"
b="x"
s="aaa;$a;zzz"
echo "a: $s"
echo "b: ${s//"$a"/"$b"}"
```

```
a: aaa;1[[[2]]]3;zzz
b: aaa;x;zzz
```

example: replace fixed string in file

```
f=input.txt
a="1[[[2]]]3"
b="x"
s=$(<$f)
echo -n "${s//"$a"/"$b"}" >$f.new
```